# VLC player takes very long to play files from a smb NAS file server

Tags: nas, vlc-media-player

I noticed that the VLC player takes about 10 to 20 seconds to start playing next mp3 and mp4 files from my smb NAS server (FRITZ!Box). Since these files play almost instantly with other players like the Windows Media Player the problem seems to be in VLC.

How can I get VLC to play as fast as other media players?

Comment: Yes, with the latest 3.0.3.

Comment: It is important to correctly set the time on the samba server, and also choose the same local time zone on both server and vlc client sides.

Answer (score 1):

In the VLC forum for example at [reduce delay ( caching ? ) of network stream](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=111431) and [How to reduce VLC buffering time when video starts??](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=113473) and at [other pages](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/change-cache-size-vlc-download-streaming-32646.html) I found some suggestions about reducing the caching of network streams by starting VLC with the options

```
--udp-caching=500 --tcp-caching=500 --realrtsp-caching=500
```

I found these options also in the GUI at

```
Tools->Preferences->All (Advanced Preferences)
```

by searching for `caching`.

Reducing the `tcp` and `udp` caching values of `Stream output` from `300` to `1` reduced the delay significantly.

Comment: That didn't help me with 3.0.8 https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/21470 - got "ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR is called too late" - interestingly Opus (audio codec) encoded files were not affected and the network bandwidth is not even close to be fully used. Looks like VLC is throttling the bandwidth for itself and then runs out of buffered data.

Answer (score 1):

I had this experience, but changing the prefetch sizes didn't really seem to make any appreciable impact. It was still taking about 20-30 seconds to open a 45 second, 17 MB file.

In my situation, I had the SMB share mounted to drive X:  I noticed that the network traffic in task manager was being tracked as a system process, not under the VLC process.  Reading another answer gave me the idea to try accessing the stream directly through the smb protocol, rather than from the Windows mount point.

```
vlc.exe X:\video.mp4
```

Took the same 20-30 seconds to load

```
vlc.exe smb://example.com/video.mp4
```

Loaded almost instantly.

While it's helpful to be able to open files faster, it's still frustrating to me, because the folder structure on the NAS is very annoying to browse through, which was why I had mounted it in Windows to begin with!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and was finally able to fix it by going to

```
VLC->Preferences->Show All (Advanced Preferences)
```

from there access stream prefetch settings:
[Input/Codec -> Stream filters -> prefetch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YU9wX.png)
and increase the sizes for Buffer Seek and Seek threshold. Increase the number based on however much RAM you are comfortable giving away to VLC.
For reference, I assigned 131072 KiB to Buffer, 67,108,864 bytes to
Read and 67,108,864 bytes to seek threshold.